# Glob for multiple substrings in a string separated by unknown number of characters

Tags: bash, glob

Lets say that I have a bunch of files in a directory and I want to list all of those which contain the words 'word1' and 'word2', but only in both words occur within a given filename.  The thing is that I do not know a priori how many characters will separate these strings.

For instance, I may have 221-word1-12345ABC-word2.dat or ce-word1-221word2.dat along with a bunch of files whose filenames may contain only word1, only word2, or neither.  How would one do this using globbing?

Comment: How would you glob for `*word1*word2*`? (That's a **big** hint)

Comment: @msw Oh, of course!  Sorry guys.

Comment: Heh, sometimes things just stare you in the face wrongly ;)

Comment: thanks @msw yeah sometimes I should just have another cup of coffee before asking a question!